# NullPointerException while Inflating dragSortListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hi I am trying to load images from server in a dragSortListView implemented using the  [library](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbauerca%2Fdrag-sort-listview&ei=catYVPCOMo6cugTfhYH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNHIcbas66kX9o7q--D37c8yVCPfTQ&sig2=TveW0SbEy-KwkYzgnJNd9w&bvm=bv.78677474,d.c2E&cad=rja) by bauerca. I have a simple layout with and imageview used as a draghandle. I have written the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortController;
import com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
DragSortListView listView;
ReorderAdapter adapter;

private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener()
{
    @Override
    public void drop(int from, int to)
    {
        if (from != to)
        {
            Model item = (Model) adapter.getItem(from);
            adapter.list.remove(from);
            adapter.list.add(to, item);
        }
    }
};

private DragSortListView.RemoveListener onRemove = new DragSortListView.RemoveListener()
{
    @Override
    public void remove(int which)
    {
        adapter.list.remove(which);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (DragSortListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] names = new String[]{"http://url1",
            "http://url2","http://url3", "http://url4"};

    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        list.add(new Model(names[i], names[i], i));
    }
    adapter = new ReorderAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setDropListener(onDrop);
    listView.setRemoveListener(onRemove);

    DragSortController controller = new DragSortController(listView);
    controller.setDragHandleId(R.id.menu);
            //controller.setClickRemoveId(R.id.);
    controller.setRemoveEnabled(false);
    controller.setSortEnabled(true);
    controller.setDragInitMode(1);
            //controller.setRemoveMode(removeMode);

    listView.setFloatViewManager(controller);
    listView.setOnTouchListener(controller);
    listView.setDragEnabled(true);
}

private class Model {
    private String text;
    private String url;
    private int position;

    public Model (String text, String url, int position) {
        this.text = text;
        this.url = url;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (((Model)o).position == this.position) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
protected DragSortListView getListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (DragSortListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
}
private class ReorderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    Context context;

    public ReorderAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Model> objects) {
        this.list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }  

        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(list.get(position).text);
        String photo_source=list.get(position).url.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        try {
            Picasso.with(context).load(photo_source)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .into(((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.menu)));
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArg){
            illegalArg.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

but I keep getting `NullPointerException` at the line when I try to get `LayoutInflater` in the `getView()` method.

below is stack trace of the exception.

```
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at com.example.dndlist.MainActivity$ReorderAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:120)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView$AdapterWrapper.getView(DragSortListView.java:730)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1845)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1661)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView.layoutChildren(DragSortListView.java:2136)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2037)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14094)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14094)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14094)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14094)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14094)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-05 10:20:21.801: E/AndroidRuntime(10513):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: its always about **NPE**  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this code,

```
private class ReorderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    Context context;

    public ReorderAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Model> objects) {
        this.list = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }  

        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(list.get(position).text);
        String photo_source=list.get(position).url.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        try {
            Picasso.with(context).load(photo_source)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .into(((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.menu)));
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArg){
            illegalArg.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

First thing is NPE came due to you not initialize context object which is you use to inflate layout as well as load image using Picasso so initialize context object in constructor :

```
this.context= context;
```

Second thing is whenever you use custom adapter always try to use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Viewholder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Viewholder();
        convertView  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.menu = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder =(Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).text);
    try {
          Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).url.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20")).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(holder.menu);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArg){
         illegalArg.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return convertView;
}

class Viewholder {
  TextView textView;
  ImageView menu;
}
```